# (Talmid) Rabbenu Yonah to Rif on Berakhot

Tags: rishonim

Who authored the commentary to the Rif on Berakhot variously referred to as 'R. Yonah', or 'talmid R. Yonah'?

Was it perhaps edited by a student as I seem to remember hearing?

Comment: The students of Rabbeinu Yonah he'Chasid (ben Avraham) of Gerondi, France (d. 1264) compiled a commentary on Berachos based on their Rebbi's teachings.  -- http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MqoAZa_g5AQJ:www.dafyomi.co.il/berachos/intro.htm+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk